# Why the same sound source (low frequency, possibly infrasound) has different frequencies in different rooms of the house?

Tags: noise, sound, detection, frequency-measurement, vibration

Can someone explain me why the same sound source has different frequencies in different rooms and if there is some type of correlation between the vibrating frequency and the distance between the sound source?

I am trying to locate the source of a low frequency sound that sounds like a diesel car engine or air compressor/pump, but when I record it, it has different frequencies in different rooms from the house.

I think this sound is near the infrasound range as you can also feel it as vibrations (my friends can also feel it, especially if they use foam earplugs). I am using a dual array mic from my laptop to record it (surprisingly, it detects low frequency sounds as I have tested it by rapidly closing the door at about 2-4Hz and the sound was detected).

The laptop array mics also record the 220V transformer at 50Hz and the fridge at 95 and 105Hz so I think it is working correctly.

I use **Spectrum Lab** app to record it.

So in one room, the frequency of the sound is ~ 16Hz and ~71Hz, while in other rooms, the same sound source (I feel the vibrations in the same way) has a frequency of 36Hz, 41Hz, 73-76Hz.

I have attached a screenshot of my recording from the 3 different rooms.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Google "Resonance".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance

Your different rooms are not the same acoustically   Every room will have a different natural resonance, so different frequencies will seem to be accentuated over others depending the dimensions of the space  you're in.

Comment: Thanks! But in this case how would I know the real frequency of the sound? As when I measure it, it shows different frequencies in different rooms.

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop has a fan running, then it is possible that you are recording the resonances in the room that are driven by the sound of the fan.

Fan sounds from a laptop are a combination of (more or less) white noise from the motion of the air, a hum or whine from the motor itself, and whistling or piping sounds due to resonances in the air ways inside the laptop.

I would try making a recording with a device that doesn't have a fan (like a smart phone) and then analysing the recording with Spectrum Lab.

There are smart phone programs that can save the recordings in a lossless format - use .wav or similar, not .mp3 or other lossy format.

Make sure the laptop is off while recording.  The same goes for other "noisy" appliances,of course.

---

You might try intentionally generating some white noise in the room as you are doing your analysis.

Spectrum Lab includes a signal generator that can make white noise.

Run the generator with the output connected to a speaker.  Average your spectrum readings, and you will see "hills" in your spectrum that at wavelengths corresponding to the size of the room.

---

I also hear low frequency sounds that no one else notices.  I've been to an ear doctor, and my hearing is normal - that sort of lets out any kind of "super hearing" or tinnitus effects.

I haven't, however, been able to reliably record anything that I could identify as the source, either.

I do know that the bass heavy music that everyone seems to love gets on my nerves - it sounds like it is **all** bass to me.  I prefer music played with the bass turned **way** down, so maybe my ears work better than average below frequencies that the ear doctors test.

It is also possible that it is all in my head.  I notice the low frequency sounds more when I'm tired or otherwise stressed, so it could all be psychosomatic (polite term for "imagining it.")

At any rate, good luck tracking down the source of your noise.

Comment: Thanks for the comment JRE. The frequency of the laptop fan is constant at 90Hz. 

When the fan stops, the 90Hz line also stops but the other lines (like 30Hz, 50HZ, 70Hz) continue to record so that is definitely not the laptop fan. I even turned off electricity to remove any disturbances from home appliances but the low frequency sound is still recorded. 

Regarding white noise/tone generator, wow I did not knew about this feature. I just checked it and I am really amazed. Thanks!  Can you provide more details about how to average spectrum reading to room frequency? How to do this?

Comment: I only know what I've read online about Spectrum Lab.  I don't know how you get it to do averaging, I just know that many such programs can average the spectrum to get a clearer reading.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ducted air-conditioning in your house, the rectangular ducts are known for "drumming" a low frequency vibration, also the various different lengths of ducting will have different longitudinal resonances, all at very low frequencies.

Secondly, do you have any flues , e.g. fireplaces or rangehoods in the kitchen, the wind blowing across the top can stimulate resonances, much the same as blowing across a milk bottle,  search for "Helmholtz resonance".

If you can get hold of a signal generator and loudspeaker, you can try sweeping the frequency slowly, you can usually hear the resonances in the room, however most bass speakers have there own resonances.

Frequencies around 16Hz would also be typically for a wall , perhaps driven by a refrigerator leaning on the other side of the wall.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. We do have a flue on the roof of the house (long chimney like in this image http://prolineli.com/wp-content/flagallery/prefabmetal-chimney/prefab9.png but without a cap). How can I check if the flue is the actual source of the sound? I already tried to measure the frequency near the flue (on the roof and in the basement) but it was not showing anything.

Also, if the flue is the actual source of the sound, how can I stop the sound (remove resonance from flue) ?

P.S. We also have rainwater down pipes installed on the outside of the house.

Comment: Well, if there is no noticable difference to the measured sound near the flue, then it is unlikely to be the culprit. 
If you had a Dynamic Signal Analyser, a pair of microphones, a speaker and some skills in modal analysis you would have a better shot at tracking it down.